# MapView not loading when in subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mkmapview

I created a custom view and I have a map in it, this is how my view is setup.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withPackage:(AftershipTracking *)package andLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SPShareView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
        [self setLabelsWithPackage:package];
        _dayLabel.text = _dayLabel.text.uppercaseString;
        [self setupMapWithPinLocation:location];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Inside of the `setupMapWithPinLocation` I have this.

```
- (void)setupMapWithPinLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 760, 560)];
    _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    _mapView.delegate = self;
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:location.coordinate];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = [_mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate , 700, 700)];
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 3;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 3;
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

}
```

However after creating the view, when I look at it in debug I get a blank map that has not been loaded yet, what would be the correct way to go about implementing this? I added the delegate methods for checking if the `MapView` loaded and they seem to never get called. Also I do not need the map to be interactive, the map can be turned into an image and that would be good.

Comment: Where do you call initWithFrame:withPackage:andLocation? and where do you add _mapView to the view hierarchy (view.addSubview(_mapView)?)

Comment: @Greg The initWithFrame is called from a separate class just by `SPShareView *shareView = [[SPShareView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 800) withPackage:_package andLocation:location];` and `_mapView` is already added in the nib. I can see the outline of the map but it hasn't loaded.

Comment: From which method is initWithFrame:withPackage:andLocation called? viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, etc?

Comment: It is called after I have geo-coded an address. Then I just pass it into the method.

Comment: Can you override didMoveToSuperview method and move to line [self setupMapWithPinLocation:location]; from initWithFrame it didMoveToSuperview.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment:

> `_mapView` is already added in the nib

A NIB isn't a magical code-generation tool, it's data. It's loaded once, then its influence is expended. When it was loaded, whatever its `mapView` described was added to the NIB. I'll bet you have a map view in your nib that `_mapView` connects to? That's the one that's displaying.

When you do this:

```
_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 760, 560)];
```

You:

1. create a new instance of `MKMapView` that nobody else knows about;
2. discard your reference to the map view that is visible on screen.

Whatever you subsequently do to `_mapView` will have no effect to the one on screen for the same reason that:

```
int a = 3;
int b = a;
b = 4;
```

... does not change the value of `a`. Changing the identity of the object that `_mapView` points to has no effect on your view hierarchy. Your views are completely unaware that you have done it.

If you have a map view in your NIB that is being created and displaying as you want then there's no reason also to create one programmatically. Delete the line quoted above and leave everything else alone.

(also: it's very odd that you want to call `initWithFrame:` and then throw away your instance for a NIB-loaded copy, which you decided not to load via `-initWithNibName:bundle:`; if you're using a NIB then you should just set your basic view properties up in the NIB)